# unexpected color cycle

Tags: graphics

I had thought that the default`ColorFunctionScaling` of`True` should preclude this outcome, but I'm seeing it in a `ListContourPlot`.

[image: unwanted color cycle]

Here is how to produce it and how to make it disappear.  With the data below, create a contour plot as

```
ListContourPlot[data, PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, 
  Contours -> {0.18, 0.21, 0.24, 0.26 , 0.29}]
```

To make it disappear, remove the last contour (0.29) from the list.  This behavior seems unexpected to me; am I right?  Here is the data.

```
data = {{200, 200, 0.14444}, {200, 1460, 0.21104}, {200, 2920, 0.22493}, {200, 4380, 0.23099}, {200, 5840, 0.235015}, {200, 7300, 0.23895}, {365, 1095, 0.2165}, {365, 2555, 0.23039}, {365, 4015, 0.236995}, {365, 5475, 0.240715}, {365, 6935, 0.243375}, {730, 730, 0.216755}, {730, 2190, 0.23781}, {730, 3650, 0.244365}, {730, 5110, 0.245795}, {730, 6570, 0.247215}, {1095, 365, 0.196715}, {1095, 1825, 0.24024}, {1095, 3285, 0.246205}, {1095, 4745, 0.24816}, {1095, 6205, 0.250295}, {1460, 200, 0.164825}, {1460, 1460, 0.23876}, {1460, 2920, 0.248155}, {1460, 4380, 0.250355}, {1460, 5840, 0.251675}, {1460, 7300, 0.25214}, {1825, 1095, 0.234915}, {1825, 2555, 0.24728}, {1825, 4015, 0.25127}, {1825, 5475, 0.253205}, {1825, 6935, 0.25335}, {2190, 730, 0.223665}, {2190, 2190, 0.247035}, {2190, 3650, 0.252185}, {2190, 5110, 0.25476}, {2190, 6570, 0.25506}, {2555, 365, 0.19305}, {2555, 1825, 0.24564}, {2555, 3285, 0.251245}, {2555, 4745, 0.25488}, {2555, 6205, 0.255725}, {2920, 200, 0.15479}, {2920, 1460, 0.242165}, {2920, 2920, 0.25029}, {2920, 4380, 0.2541}, {2920, 5840, 0.255705}, {2920, 7300, 0.25819}, {3285, 1095, 0.23685}, {3285, 2555, 0.25072}, {3285, 4015, 0.254635}, {3285, 5475, 0.25592}, {3285, 6935, 0.25765}, {3650, 730, 0.22109}, {3650, 2190, 0.248635}, {3650, 3650, 0.25533}, {3650, 5110, 0.255505}, {3650, 6570, 0.25745}, {4015, 365, 0.185125}, {4015, 1825, 0.24541}, {4015, 3285, 0.253485}, {4015, 4745, 0.257255}, {4015, 6205, 0.25755}, {4380, 200, 0.14659}, {4380, 1460, 0.24032}, {4380, 2920, 0.252895}, {4380, 4380, 0.256205}, {4380, 5840, 0.25757}, {4380, 7300, 0.259515}, {4745, 1095, 0.23148}, {4745, 2555, 0.250825}, {4745, 4015, 0.25602}, {4745, 5475, 0.257245}, {4745, 6935, 0.25978}, {5110, 730, 0.2139}, {5110, 2190, 0.249725}, {5110, 3650, 0.255415}, {5110, 5110, 0.258355}, {5110, 6570, 0.258835}, {5475, 365, 0.17846}, {5475, 1825, 0.24442}, {5475, 3285, 0.253195}, {5475, 4745, 0.2582}, {5475, 6205, 0.258875}, {5840, 200, 0.141915}, {5840, 1460, 0.237555}, {5840, 2920, 0.25181}, {5840, 4380, 0.255225}, {5840, 5840, 0.25872}, {5840, 7300, 0.260545}, {6205, 1095, 0.22698}, {6205, 2555, 0.248865}, {6205, 4015, 0.25566}, {6205, 5475, 0.25899}, {6205, 6935, 0.26062}, {6570, 730, 0.207625}, {6570, 2190, 0.246365}, {6570, 3650, 0.254875}, {6570, 5110, 0.25757}, {6570, 6570, 0.260675}, {6935, 365, 0.171975}, {6935, 1825, 0.2413}, {6935, 3285, 0.252385}, {6935, 4745, 0.258305}, {6935, 6205, 0.25805}, {7300, 200, 0.13619}, {7300, 1460, 0.23253}, {7300, 2920, 0.24987}, {7300, 4380, 0.25617}, {7300, 5840, 0.257875}, {7300, 7300, 0.25954}}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Is it that the shade of gray of the top values is too similar to the shade of gray of the bottom values? The code that you posted shows plots in color and they do not have this problem.

Comment: @C.E. Thank you for looking.  Please set the `ColorFunction` to `GrayLevel`.  And yes, I believe that the default value of `True` for `ColorFunctionScaling` should preclude the dark shade at the top.  I actually suspect this is a bug, but I am prepared to learn otherwise.

Comment: @Alan, I think this looks like a bug too. You should submit it to Wolfram.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me too.